# Twilio integrate whatsapp using conversation

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to use conversation provided by twilio and add whatsapp number as an SMS participant? I tried using conversation to integrate slack but not sure how to replicate for whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation showing how to add a WhatsApp user into a Twilio Conversation.

Conversation Participant Resource

https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource

The WhatsApp syntax is to prefix the number with whatsapp:, such as shown here.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.  

Problem Statement : Currently we have our customers using various chat platforms such as whatsapp , and slack where our contact center is forced to use the same.

However, we would like to give Twilio flex platform to our contact service team so that they can reply messages coming from whatsapp, slack.

Can you please help me to understand how to achieve this using twilio platform. 
Also I am trying to understand the use of twilio conversations.